# Synthesizing Shift left by 1 with just NAND gates?

Tags: binary, cpu, bitwise-operators, division

I have an algorithm that performs division of 2 64-bit unsigned integers using C bitwise operators (<<, &, ^, |, ~) in a loop.

Now I would like to eliminate shift left << operator completely to understand how this is done as I can already synthesize AND, OR, XOR, NOT using NAND gates.

Is it possible to perform left shift by 1 with JUST NAND gates too? I have read a little about flip-flops in electronics but I'm implementing this in pure software just to understand it.

I want to avoid using << or >> operators completely and do not want to use existing arithmetic operators from any computer language including assembly.

Comment: as far as I can tell you can left shift by one with just wires

Answer (score 7):

In hardware, you can implement left shift by 1 without any logic gates at all. Just wire the data lines like so:

[image: Left shift by one]

If you want something more generic, you could implement a [barrel shifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter). This can be synthesised from multiplexers:

[image: Barrel shifter]
<sub>(source: [books24x7.com](http://images.books24x7.com/bookimages/id_7951/fig9-1.jpg))</sub>

which in turn can be synthesised from NAND gates.

Here is a comprehensive master's thesis on the subject: [Barrel Shifter
Design,
Optimization, and
Analysis](https://preserve.lehigh.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1714&context=etd).